# Using different 'select' for same template (avoiding repetition)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xhtml

Here is the simplified problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="foo" select="'test'"/> <!-- 'test' can also be empty '' or whatever -->

    <!-- XHTML validation -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" 
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
        indent="yes"
        encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>bar</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:choose>

                    <xsl:when test="string-length($foo)=0">
                        <ol>
                            <xsl:for-each select="something/something2"> <!-- SEE THIS? -->
                                <li>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="generic" />
                                </li>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ol>
                    </xsl:when>

                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <ol>
                            <xsl:for-each select="something/something2[tmp = $foo"]> <!-- SO MUCH REPETITION!! -->
                                <li>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="generic" />
                                </li>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ol>
                    </xsl:otherwise>

                </xsl:choose>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think it's pretty straight forward: how can I avoid this repetition? I tried using `xsl:if` to set a `xsl:variable` but then I cannot use the variable outside of the `if` so it becomes useless.

Similarly, I want to only have the `<ol>` only applied when `<xsl:if test="count($varYouMightFigureOut) > 1">`, else, it should only be `<xsl:call-template name="generic" />` that is called on its own (the `for-each` and `<li>` become irrelevant and shouldn't be displayed). Again: a trivial solution involves a lot of repetition, but I would much rather avoid such a thing.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this repetition by fully embracing the inner beauty of XSLT.
Make use of the template feature like demonstrated in the following example:

Reduce the central template to its essentials:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>bar</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

And add two sub-templates implementing the last `IF` condition on a hypothetical root `<root>` element (Its name has to be identical to the name of the XML root element)

```
<xsl:template match="root">
   <xsl:call-template name="generic" />
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="root[$varYouMightFigureOut > 1]">
   <ol>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
   </ol>
</xsl:template>
```

Then condense the two `xsl:choose` possibilities to these two templates:

```
<xsl:template match="something/something2[string-length($foo)=0]">
   <li>
       <xsl:call-template name="generic" />
   </li>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="something/something2[tmp = $foo]">
   <li>
       <xsl:call-template name="generic" />
   </li>
</xsl:template>
```

(You can add parameters to the `xsl:call-template` if necessary).

And complete this with a placeholder "generic" template used by the above templates:

```
<xsl:template name="generic">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
</xsl:template>
```

This solution avoids all unnecessary repetition and makes use of the power of XSLT.